# Why is UITextView not scrolling when entered text reaches the level of the keyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I have an iPhone screen (see attached image) where the UITextView fills almost the entire screen. When the user taps in the control the keyboard is displayed and text can be entered. However, when the text reaches the level of the top of the keyboard the UITextView does not scroll the entered text up. The result is you can not see the remaining text that is entered. Swiping up in the UITextView does not scroll the text up either. Scrolling is enabled in the UITextView.

[image]

How do you get the UITextView to automatically scroll as the text entry reaches the level of the top of the keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UITextView scrolls automatically when text reaches its own height limit not keyboard or another object blocking the UITextView.

Maybe you can resize your UITextView when it becomes first responder to be of the height visible on the screen and resizes back to take the whole screen when it resign been first responder.